# How do I stop Java moving from the last to the first entry of a database?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I want to stop my 'Next' button from going beyond the last record in a DB that my Java program is reading from.

Similarly, I don't want my 'Previous' button going from the first back to the last.

I've hit a wall!

This is my code behind the 'Next' button

}

```
public void nextButtonPressed(ActionEvent e) {

    currentEntryIndex++;
    if (currentEntryIndex >= numberOfEntries){
        currentEntryIndex = 0;
    }
```

Any advice?

Thanks,
C

Comment: Why don't you disable the button when it gets to the last entry?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dan.

C

Answer (score 2):

You could test that it is less than the `numberOfEntries` before you increment. Something like,

```
public void nextButtonPressed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (currentEntryIndex < numberOfEntries) {
        currentEntryIndex++;
    }
}
```

And similarly with "Previous" test that you are `> 0` before subtracting one.

Comment: Once I got the syntax to behave itself, that worked nicely.

Cheers!